# Is it possible to to make SVG image from Text?

Tags: svg

For example, imagine the text "`URL`". 
I understand that there is SVG Text and SVG image.

Is it possible to create and image that can be used in an `<img>` tag from text (without drawing the line of the text)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) with the SVG text in it if you want...

```html
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text x="0" y="35">URL</text></svg>'>
```