# Is it possible to a make stand-alone SVG image file from Text?

Tags: svg

For example, imagine the text "UP". I understand that there is SVG Text and SVG image.

Is it possible to create and image file (e.g. tab.svg) that can be used as an icon? (for example a contextMenu icon)

The example given in [Is it possible to to make SVG image from Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251122/is-it-possible-to-to-make-svg-image-from-text) works fine as data URI but remains as Text when opened directly and does not work/display as context Menu icon.

**More Info**

Example of path based SVG: `check.svg`

```
<!-- This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
   - License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
   - file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill="context-fill" d="M6 14a1 1 0 0 1-.707-.293l-3-3a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414l2.157 2.157 6.316-9.023a1 1 0 0 1 1.639 1.146l-7 10a1 1 0 0 1-.732.427A.863.863 0 0 1 6 14z"/>
</svg>
```

If `check.svg` is opened by the browser (e.g. file:///C:/...e/check.svg), browser displays it as Image (although it is only a check mark).

`check.svg` can be set as the `src` for an `img`. It can also be set as contextMenu image/icon in Firefox (and other supporting browsers).

Example of text based SVG: `url.svg`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text x="0" y="35">URL</text></svg>
```

If `url.svg` is opened by the browser (e.g. file:///C:/...e/url.svg), browser displays it as TEXT. Each letter can be selected.

`url.svg` can be set as the `src` for an `img`. It will then display as image.

However, it can not be set as contextMenu image/icon in Firefox. It does not display.

Am I missing something or is it not possible to use TEXT based SVG in this way?

Comment: you can just use the content of the data uri in my previous answer as tab.svg

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text x="0" y="35">URL</text></svg>`

Comment: I created a file called tab.svg from your comment and it displays perfectly well in my copy of Firefox.

Comment: Example: url.svg ...if opened directly with browser it displays as TEXT and not as image. I can select U and R and L separately like any other text. If the url.svg is set to an img src, then it displays it as Image. If I set it to a Firefox contextMenu icon, it fails. TBH, That is where I was hoping to use it.

Comment: images are not interactive. You can't select their contents. When SVG is used as an image it acts like a raster.

Comment: Normal image type SVG, once opened directly with browser, still renders as image but above renders as text.

Comment: That's not SVG used as an image, that's SVG as a document. SVG as an image would be via an <img> tag or as a CSS background-image etc.

Comment: I will add more info to the original post.

Comment: Try adding width and height attributes to the <svg> element that are not percentages.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't display at all even if opened by the browser `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="#000">
  <text x="0" y="35">URL</text>
</svg>`

Comment: Also tried it without.. same result. Do yo have a working example?

Comment: adjust the viewBox values.